# Проверить, является ли дата прошедшей в momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Привет. Как можно проверить, прошла ли уже определённая дата в momentjs? Например, сегодня `08.07.2017`, а вчерашняя дата - `07.07.2017`.

Comment: Документация https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-before/. Там же все ясно, с примерами.